# What trophies are available in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have a couple of trophies on Trello, one each for downloading the iOS and the Android app. I was wondering what other trophies are there.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a public list.

Take a look at the Trello trophy list one team member, [Bobby Grace has, here](https://trello.com/bobbygrace).

This is typical for other team members too.

Comment: UPDATE:  January 14, 2014  Trello released a new version that shows  trophies you have and have yet to attain.  View on your profile by clicking your name (top right) then selecting Profile.

Comment: There are still secret trophies though. Shhhh